# How do you create a new user with admin permissions in ADS?

Tags: database, command, advantage-database-server

What is the command to make a new user with administrator privileges in the Advantage Database Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SQL you can do the following

```
--Create User
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_CreateUser('username', 'password', 'comment');

--Add the user to the DB:Admin group
EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_AddUserToGroup('username','DB:Admin');
```